# Unserialized object can't be passed from origin?

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5.1

So I have a complex object which I wish to cache after creation as it is expensive to initialize. I'm able to reconstitute an instance *within the class defining file* but I need to be able to return the reconstituted instance in place of a `new MyClass` if my scheme is going to be of any use. (Don't I?)

Here's what I've done so far:

```
class PayPeriodService
{
    public $type;           // weekly,bi-weekly, semi-monthly, monthlly
    public $payday_first;
    public $close_first;
    public $hours_start;
    public $hours_end;
    public $length;         // in days
    public $periods;        // array of all periods this year
    public $dayInterval;
    public $oneWeekInterval;
    public $twoWeekInterval;
    public $semiFirstInterval;
    public $monthInterval;
    public $initialYear;
    public $today;          // date object

    public function __construct()
    {
        if( Redis::exists('pay-period-instance')) {
            Log:info( 'Fetching Pay-Period from cache.');
            $instance = json_decode(Redis::get('pay-period-instance'));
//            var_dump( $instance );
//            exit();
            return $instance;
        }
        return $this->init();
    }


    public function init()
    {
        Log::info('Reconstituting Pay-Period from primitive definition.');

        $ppdef = PayPeriod::all()->last();
        // etc etc etc, setting up all the properties, loading arrays etc

        // finally I cache the object 
        Redis::set('pay-period-instance', json_encode($this));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

So when I instantiate this class, with `$ppsvc = new PayPeriodService;` in another class, the $instance variable in the PayPeriodService file is valid and fully reconsituted, fully functional. But the returned instance in $ppsvc is a mindless zombie shell of what it ought to be: no instance data, no methods.

What is the magic I need to invoke to get the restored object to travel abroad as it needs must do?  I have explored the Serializable interface, and tried with un/serialize in place of the json_encode/decode with no significant change to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *__construct()* method does NOT return anything. What you want is a singleton (AFAICU).

Look at this example:

```
class A {}

class B {
  public function __construct(){return new A;}
}

$b = new B;

print_r($b); // B
```

So has you see even having the constructor returning a different class, that is not going to happen. There are several ways to accomplish this, so you can take a look on the web.

A simple example:

```
class PayPeriodService {

  /**
   * @var self
   */
  static private $instance;

  // private removes the possibility to make a new instance
  private function __construct()
  {
    // object construction logic here
  }

  /**
   * @return PayPeriodService
   */
  static public function getInstance()
  {
    if(!self::$instance)
    {
      self::$instance = new static;
    }

    return self::$instance;
  }
}

$ppsv = PayPeriodService::getInstance(); // will return what you intend
```

Unless the object is constantly mutating on Redis, this will do the trick. But you can easily adapt if needed